# Gradle dependency resolving to lower version

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

According to my knowledge gradle should resolve to latest dependencies when there is conflict

but in following dependency tree i can see lower dependency is getting resolved can anyone tell me why this is happening

> org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.2 -> 2.13.3

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.8
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11 -> 1.2.3
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.2 -> 2.13.3
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.36 -> 1.7.30
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
```

And my gradle.build file looks like this

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '2.0.0'
id 'java'
id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.3'
}

group = 'com.cox.cns'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
developmentOnly
  runtimeClasspath {
    extendsFrom developmentOnly
 }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.55'
implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.7.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.8'
implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'){
exclude group : 'org.springframework.boot' , module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:1.0.8'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.11.964'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.851'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws- 
messaging:2.2.6.RELEASE'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}

}
```

Comment: That is the Spring Dependency plugin at work. One thing you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring Boot never mix jars from different versions as that will eventually lead to issues. If you want to override a dependency version the how to is explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can get what you want by simply overriding the main jar.

```
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.2'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
    implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'
    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.7.0'
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
//    {
//        exclude group : 'org.springframework.boot' , module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'
//    }
//implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.8'
```

you can verify before and after with `./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency log4j-to-slf4j`

Comment: can we execute dependencyInsight from STS gradle tasks view